# Arduino DUE + FT-CAN

Tags: arduino

I have an Arduino Due and I have an application that uses FT-CAN (11898-3, Low speed Can). Does anyone know if the Can controller built in the DUE micro will control FT-CAN Transceivers TJA1054t or TJA1055.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I heard that the CAN is not hooked up on the Due but I might confused.

Either way the best answer is to recommend the Arduino.cc forum which would give you an answer very quickly. http://www.arduino.cc/forum

Comment: Arduino Due does support CAN. I have HS CAN working but I never figured out if Low Speed CAN will work. There is a great library named due_can made by Collin Kidder. He did a great job.